# Add break line in foreach loop php

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach

I have this code

```
$myurl = file_get_contents('https://myurl.html');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($myurl);
$divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');

foreach($divs as $div) {
    if ($div->getAttribute('id') === 'j-product-desc') {
        echo "<br/>".$div->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

**Result:** It is displaying result something like this with no break line.

Item specifics Item Type: Jewelry Packaging & Display Material: Acrylic Jewelry Packaging & Display Type: Cases & Displays Item Length: 16.5 cm

**Required Result** I want result like this with break after every specification.

Item specifics

Item Type: Jewelry Packaging & Display

Material: Acrylic Jewelry Packaging & Display

Type: Cases & Displays

Item Length: 16.5 cm

Comment: Is the entire string in a single `nodeValue`?

Comment: yes entire string in a single nodeValue

Comment: Then you're going to have difficulty. You'll need to work out what the rules are for where the each part of the attribute begins and ends and split the string accordingly and then output with HTML `<br />` tags. What would make things easier is if there are newlines already in the text. If you view-source in your browser, are they on different lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$myurl = file_get_contents('https://myurl.html');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($myurl);
$divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');

foreach($divs as $div) {
    if ($div->getAttribute('id') === 'j-product-desc') {
        $desc = str_replace("\n", '<br>', $div->nodeValue);
        echo "<br/>".$desc;
    }
}
```